# A question about homomorphisms between finite abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G,A,B$ denote finite abelian $p$-groups.

Suppose that $B$ is proper subgroup of $A$ with ${\rm rank}(A)={\rm rank}(B)$.

**Question:** What are equivalent conditions to say that ${\rm Hom}(G,A)={\rm Hom}(G,B)$?

One way could be the following which, I am not sure.

Suppose $p^m$ be the minimum order of an element of $A\setminus B$. Then 
$${\rm Hom}(G,A)={\rm Hom}(G,B) \Longleftrightarrow {\rm exponent}(G)<p^m.$$
Is this correct interpretation? What could be other simple equivalent interpretations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is when every homomorphism from $G$ to $A$ has image
within $B$.

Well, $G$ is the direct product of cyclic groups so we can reduce
to $G$ cyclic. The maps from a cyclic group $C_{p^k}$ to $A$
correspond to the subgroup $A[p^k]$, the $p^k$-torsion elements of $A$.
So $\mathrm{Hom}(C_{p^k},A)=\mathrm{Hom}(C_{p^k},B)$ iff
$A[p^k]=B[p^k]$ iff every element of $A-B$ has exponent $\ge p^{k+1}$.

In the general case, apply this to all cyclic summands of $G$. The
largest of these will be $C_{p^r}$ where $p^r$ is the exponent of $G$.
Therefore $\mathrm{Hom}(G,A)=\mathrm{Hom}(G,B)$ iff the order of
all the elements of $A-B$ have order greater than the exponent of $G$.
This verifies your criterion.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.